# Is it possible to play the Facebook live video in the Android WebView?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, webview

I have got the video id of the live_video using `Facebook` `GraphRequest`. but the live video does not play in the `WebView`. Other videos play fine. If I play same link in the web browser it plays the live video properly.

Comment: Were you able to play the facebook live video? If so, how did you do it. Using webview, videoview or a custom video player

Comment: Use Url provided by the graph response in the Webview, other alternatives not possible right now.

Comment: Yeah that's what I've done but I intent to load the link in a custom player.   It isnt possible ?

Comment: yes that's  not possible right now

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation it is NOT possible. Please check this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/faq and take a look at the first question titled: "Live on Mobile".

but you can try with a VideoView, please keep me informed if you try it.

Comment: yes for sure, if i try this in future. I tried this earlier, `Facebook` live stream worked well in the 6.0 `Android` `WebView` and above not in the lower API.

Comment: Can we get the facebook dash link and play with exoplayer ??